# How to verify a .edu using a python script?

Tags: python, scripting, automation

I am in a scripting class that seems to be learn-on-the-fly style. Being a n00b at programming, let alone scripting, I am more than lost. I need to come up with a python script that checks a url to verify that it is a .edu

I have little idea where to start other than the fact that I know I will have to tell python that something like www.EDUcation.com is unacceptable and tell python that okay.EDU is acceptable. I also feel like an "if than" statement will need to be used somewhere. And I know I will have to do some kind of query. I have no idea how to do this though.

I just don't know where to start.

Help me please.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a regex expression. A regex expression matches a pattern of a string. Regex can be wide and entire books have been written about it, but there are pre-written regexes all over the internet for e-mail matching. [Here's](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/regex/regular-expressions-in-python) a small Python regex tutorial. Good luck!

Comment: Can the `.edu` be followed by a country code, eg `.edu.au` ?

Comment: Thanks for the extremely fast feedback! I'm reading it presently.

Answer (score 1):

How do you, as a human, tell if the domain has the edu TLD? You look to see if it ends with ".edu", right?

```
def is_edu_domain(domain):
    return domain.endswith(".edu")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant is to do something like that:

```
def IsEDU(url):
    if url.startswith('http'):
        return url.split('/')[2].endswith('.edu')
    return url.split('/')[0].endswith('.edu') # if there's no http:// or https:// prefix
```